# navigating to a particular slide using $state.go in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a state called `deployment`
It's html looks like this:

```
<ion-slide-box>
  <ion-slide>
  </ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Now, when I use `$state.go('deployment'', {}, {reload:true})`, it navigates to second slide of deployment state.

I tried using active-slide directive and setting it before using state.go but it did not help.

How do i navigate to the first slide?

Comment: update your question with `deployment` controller.

Comment: Try with $state.go('deployment') without any parameters and make sure that your state deployment is available

Comment: I did. That did not make any difference

Comment: $mudasser: The only controller that I have in my app has nothing to do with deployment state except for $state.go once . Also, I have tried with and without parameters. It goes to second slide only and I am not really doing anything to slides from my controller.

Comment: @SimranKaur please make some codepen for this so we can see how you are doing things.